# Alarm repeating only on weekdays

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); // Tue, Wed... 
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7*24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

this will fire once a week at monday but:
I would like to set pending alarm intent only at weekdays (without saturday and sunday), how to do it only by using one intent ?
I don't want to use 5 different PendingIntents with 5 different ID's, because then I have to cancel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

Create **setAlarm** method:

```
public void setAlarm(long interval){ 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //Alarm will go off at 1
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pi); 
}
```

Create **cancelAlarm** method (optional, if you want to use it somewhere):

```
public void cancelAlarm(Context context){
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
}
```

check the day in your `onReceive()`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //Sunday = 1, Saterday = 7
    switch(day){

        case 6:  //Friday
            long interval = 3*24*60*60*1000 //skip saterday and sunday
            setAlarm(interval);

        case 2: //Monday
            setAlarm(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);  //Alarm will repeat everyday, until friday
        break;
}
```

**PS:** Don't forget to set your alarm somewhere for the **first** time using: `setAlarm(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);`

I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to set a calendar to multiple dates, so you cannot do it the way you'd like.

What I would suggest you do is make the alarm repeat daily and check in the onReceive what day it is, if it's saturday/sunday just return right away and don't do any thing.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyClass.class), 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pi);
```

receiver

```
public class MyClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (today == sunday || today == saturday) {
            return;
        }

        // do normal stuff.
    }
}
```